# How react native components behave at run time as view, ViewGroup or Fragments?

Tags: android, react-native

> In React native we create components as:-

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
 render() {
    return (
      <View >
      </View> 
    )
  }
}
```

> and make a Android build but when its run on android OS then these
>   components will convert into which android component (fragment, View
>   or ViewGroup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically In android Its Invoke A single activity (MainActivity) and
>   inside it a single view [ReactRootView](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactRootView.java) rendered something like fragment
>   renders in activity. All React native components render inside  single
>   ReactRootView.

for more details :- 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps

Comment: Is that mean There is no 'Real View' in Android View hierarchy except ReactRootView but in children of ReactRootView?